# IIS not working on public IP

Tags: windows-7, port-forwarding, iis, windows-firewall

I forwarded port 8080 to my local IP, and set in IIS that port is 8080, and when I type 192.168.1.123:8080 it is working, byt when I type like public_ip:8080 it isn't. I added inbound and outbound rules in Firewall, and it isnt working even when I turn FW off. OS is Windows 7.

Any sugestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you typing `public_ip:8080` from inside your lan, or from another network?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain both, and I get same response: "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to..."

Comment: Your inside the lan test will only work if you have a router that supports [Hairpin NAT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047391/nat-translation-not-working-from-inside-the-network-hairpin-condition) (Not all routers do!). If you run a program like wireshark on the server and somone outside the network tries to connect, do any packets ever get to your computer? If you try a port other than 8080 does it work then (Your ISP may block both port 80 and 8080 for inbound traffic)?

Comment: it is actually very common these days for ISPs to block 80 and 8080 among other common ports. It is often against the EULA for a typical home connection to run a web server.